# Why when sharing Link from my site ON SOCIAL MEDIA it display local ip address?

Tags: windows-10, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy, odoo-11

Why when sharing Link from my site ON SOCIAL MEDIA it display local ip address?
I am hosting odoo11 flatform of my local computer
OS- Windows 10, IIS, reverse proxy

it appears like this

[appears like this see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCnrf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look like you only set the iis reverse proxy inbound rule which only rewrites your page. to rewrite your page image, link etc content you need to use the outbound rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.2.51/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://192.168.2.51/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://www.example.com/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```